# Get user last accessed website URL and Name

Tags: 2010, powershell, forms-authentication

Is there is any option get user last accessed website URL based on given user name in SharePoint using Powershell or from Database.

This is an SharePoint 2010 FAB based site.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we can't get from SharePoint. Usually you have an environment where a user signs in to the network and is authorized to access the company intranet without further password requirements in a single sign on environment. But the information isn't stored in SharePoint, so we can't get it from there.

However, the information is stored in Active Directory, and by importing it, you can get the information when all of your users where last active (logon) on your domain.

```
# Load the SharePoint cmdlets
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'} 
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{    
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"    
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"  -EA SilentlyContinue
}

# Import ActiveDirectory cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Here's the function that will return the last logon date and time
function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName)
{
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $time = 0
  foreach($dc in $dcs)
  { 
    $hostname = $dc.HostName
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon 
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time) 
    {
      $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
  }
  $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
  Write-Host $username "last logged on at:" $dt 
}

# Get the user profiles
$site = Get-SPSite "https://intranet.company.com/"
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context) 
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

# Iterate all profiles and grab the users last logon date time and write to console
foreach($user in $profiles)
{
     Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName $user["UserName"]
}
```

So the answer to your question is No, not out of the box. The only thing you can get is when a user last logged on to the domain.

Comment: I will try and let u know.